# How to issue ticket in Amadeus after flight-order request?

Tags: amadeus

```
{
   "data":{
      "type":"flight-order",
      "id":"eJzTd9cPijL1Cg8FAAuUAn0%3D",
      "associatedRecords":[
         {
            "reference":"RZ5JWU",
            "creationDate":"2022-01-13T05:40:00.000",
            "originSystemCode":"GDS",
            "flightOfferId":"1"
         }
      ],
      "flightOffers":[
         {
            "type":"flight-offer",
            "id":"1",
            "source":"GDS",
            "nonHomogeneous":false,
            "lastTicketingDate":"2022-03-31",
            "itineraries":[
               {
                  "segments":[
                     {
                        "departure":{
                           "iataCode":"ISB",
                           "at":"2022-03-30T01:40:00"
                        },
                        "arrival":{
                           "iataCode":"DXB",
                           "terminal":"1",
                           "at":"2022-03-31T03:55:00"
                        },
                        "carrierCode":"PK",
                        "number":"233",
                        "aircraft":{
                           "code":"320"
                        },
                        "operating":{
                           
                        },
                        "id":"1",
                        "numberOfStops":0,
                        "co2Emissions":[
                           {
                              "weight":141,
                              "weightUnit":"KG",
                              "cabin":"ECONOMY"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ],
            "price":{
               "currency":"PKR",
               "total":"25235.00",
               "base":"15190.00",
               "fees":[
                  {
                     "amount":"0.00",
                     "type":"TICKETING"
                  },
                  {
                     "amount":"0.00",
                     "type":"SUPPLIER"
                  },
                  {
                     "amount":"0.00",
                     "type":"FORM_OF_PAYMENT"
                  }
               ],
               "grandTotal":"25234.00",
               "billingCurrency":"PKR"
            },
            "pricingOptions":{
               "fareType":[
                  "PUBLISHED"
               ],
               "includedCheckedBagsOnly":true
            },
            "validatingAirlineCodes":[
               "PK"
            ],
            "travelerPricings":[
               {
                  "travelerId":"1",
                  "fareOption":"STANDARD",
                  "travelerType":"ADULT",
                  "price":{
                     "currency":"PKR",
                     "total":"25234.00",
                     "base":"15190.00",
                     "taxes":[
                        {
                           "amount":"5000.00",
                           "code":"RG"
                        },
                        {
                           "amount":"2000.00",
                           "code":"SP"
                        },
                        {
                           "amount":"2800.00",
                           "code":"YD"
                        },
                        {
                           "amount":"244.00",
                           "code":"ZR"
                        }
                     ],
                     "refundableTaxes":"10044.00"
                  },
                  "fareDetailsBySegment":[
                     {
                        "segmentId":"1",
                        "cabin":"ECONOMY",
                        "fareBasis":"VLOWPK",
                        "class":"V",
                        "includedCheckedBags":{
                           "weight":30,
                           "weightUnit":"KG"
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ],
      "travelers":[
         {
            "id":"1",
            "dateOfBirth":"2003-01-03",
            "gender":"FEMALE",
            "name":{
               "firstName":"Fakhar",
               "lastName":"Khan"
            },
            "documents":[
               {
                  "number":"AG324234234",
                  "issuanceDate":"2015-01-17",
                  "expiryDate":"2025-01-17",
                  "issuanceCountry":"PK",
                  "issuanceLocation":"Pakistan",
                  "nationality":"PK",
                  "documentType":"PASSPORT",
                  "holder":true
               }
            ],
            "contact":{
               "purpose":"STANDARD",
               "phones":[
                  {
                     "deviceType":"MOBILE",
                     "countryCallingCode":"92",
                     "number":"3452345678"
                  }
               ],
               "emailAddress":"hamidafridi.droidor@gmail.com"
            }
         }
      ],
      "remarks":{
         "general":[
            {
               "subType":"GENERAL_MISCELLANEOUS",
               "text":"ONLINE BOOKING FROM INCREIBLE VIAJES"
            }
         ]
      },
      "ticketingAgreement":{
         "option":"DELAY_TO_CANCEL",
         "delay":"6D"
      },
      "contacts":[
         {
            "addresseeName":{
               "firstName":"PABLO RODRIGUEZ"
            },
            "address":{
               "lines":[
                  "Calle Prado, 16"
               ],
               "postalCode":"28014",
               "countryCode":"ES",
               "cityName":"Madrid"
            },
            "purpose":"STANDARD",
            "phones":[
               {
                  "deviceType":"LANDLINE",
                  "countryCallingCode":"34",
                  "number":"480080071"
               },
               {
                  "deviceType":"MOBILE",
                  "countryCallingCode":"33",
                  "number":"480080072"
               }
            ],
            "companyName":"INCREIBLE VIAJES",
            "emailAddress":"support@increibleviajes.es"
         }
      ]
   },
   "dictionaries":{
      "locations":{
         "ISB":{
            "cityCode":"ISB",
            "countryCode":"PK"
         },
         "DXB":{
            "cityCode":"DXB",
            "countryCode":"AE"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I request for create-order then returned #PNR and now want to issue ticket. #Amadeus

Comment: And what's your question about this? If there is an API endpoint available for this action, call it. If there is none, contact the maintainers of that API to ask for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now, this Flight Create Orders API allows you to book a flight and generate a PNR, but it does not allow for ticketing. Therefore, one of the requirements in order to use the API in production is to sign a contract with an airline consolidator to issue tickets.

Please check the [requirements](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-create-orders) on the API page. If you want help to find a consolidator get in touch with us via the [support](https://developers.amadeus.com/support) channel and we can recommend you one.

Comment: The support channel has not responded to my request for more information - is there another way I can get this info?