# After Creating Order

Tags: amadeus

After I create order using the amadeus self service and a PNR is return. Is the order confirm and can the passenger travel with that PNR or they need ticket issue? If they do how would I go about to get it?

Comment: Also this is base on production  after signing all agreement with amadeus for self service

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to issue ticket in Amadeus after flight-order request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71045782/how-to-issue-ticket-in-amadeus-after-flight-order-request)